# 'Other element would receive the click' when working with WebDriverWait in Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click on an element using Selenium in Python. When I run the code, I receive the following error message:

> ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element
>   ... is not clickable at point (946,
>   81).

Other element would receive the click:

I am trying to use WebDriverWait to do an explicit wait, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have tried:

a) waiting for my desired element to be clickable:

```
WebDriverWait(browser.driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ShadowModeAnchor.adminShadowUser"))
            )
```

b) waiting for the element named in the error message above to go invisible:

```
WebDriverWait(browser.driver, 10).until(
            EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@style='background-color: #000;  /*needs to be BELOW popup*//*z-index: 3;*/  filter: alpha(opacity=0); opacity:0.0; height: 720px; width: 100%;  position: absolute;  top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; '"))
            )
```

In both cases, I get the same error message listed above. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: What is the website you are trying to use.

Comment: show url so we could see HTML. What element do you try to click ? Links and buttons are clickable but other element may not be clicked - and they may need javascript to click them. If other element hides element which you try to click (ie. pop up mesage) then it may not be clickable.

Comment: @arundeepchohan Sharing the link would unfortunately not help, because it's a password protected site.

Comment: @furas To clarify, if I wait long enough, the element I want to click (ID="ShadowModeUser...") becomes clickable. It's just that when the page is loading, it is obscured by another element. I'm trying to figure out a way for the script to know when it can safely click on the element I want, without hardcoding a wait time.

Comment: as I know `WebDriverWait` tests it every 0.5s and it returns as soon as it is accessible - so use longer time. If it is not enough then put it in try/except to catch error and repeate it in loop - but it would be easier to use much longer time.

Comment: @furas thank you. I’d prefer not to hard code a specific time, but I will try a try/except approach.